# Terraform formatlist - format string to list

Tags: terraform

Trying to formatlist function in terraform to produce an output. 
I am looking for an output something like this

```
example.com:  [ns1.aws.com,
               ns2.aws.com,
               ns3.aws.com]
```

I have output framed something like this

```
output "example_name_servers" {

  value = "${
    formatlist(
      "{\"%v\": \"%v\"}",
      aws_route53_zone.example.*.name,
      aws_route53_zone.example.*.name_servers,
    )
  }"
}
```

Apprently it throws an error as

```
formatlist: list has a non-string element (string) in:
```

however `aws_route53_zone.main.*.name_servers` is a list.

Answer (score 0):

I joined the elements into string at formatlist

```
output "example_name_servers" {

  value = "${
    formatlist(
      "{\"%v\": \"%v\"}",
      aws_route53_zone.example.*.name,
      join(", ", aws_route53_zone.example.*.name_servers),
    )
  }"
}
```